# Issue while getting routeParams in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two separate controllers on same page which need a `GET` param from the url. The following is my template

```
  body(ng-app='application')
    .loader(ng-controller="loaderCtrl" data-ng-class="{'hidden': counter == 0}")
      #bar
    div(ng-include="'/components/nav/nav.html'")
    div(ng-view)
    div(ng-include="'/components/footer/footer.html'")
    script(src='app.js')
    script(src='//localhost:35729/livereload.js')
```

The first controller is for `nav` and the other is for the template from `ng-view`.

I am able to get the parameters properly inside `ng-view` controller but the same is not working in `navController`. Both the controllers have a simple script as

```
module.exports = function($scope,Restangular,$localStorage,$routeParams){
  console.log($routeParams);
}
```

The result that i get in both cases for same page is different. The results being

```
Object {  }  app.js:576:5
Object { q: "test" }  app.js:383:3
```

The empty being from controller from `nav` template and the other being from `ng-view`. Where am i going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ngRoute documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams). Try use `$route.current.params`, because when controller is inicializing `$routeParams` are empty.